# rspec test failing on expect(user.save).to be_true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Using rails 4.1.8 and rspec 3.2.1

This test passes in other applications where my rspec gem is 2.0.

It also works in development mode just fine. If I create a user with an email in all caps, it get saved in the database as lowercase.

This is my fail message:

```
Failures:

  1) User validations #downcase_email downcases an email before saving
     Failure/Error: expect(user.save).to be_true
       expected false to respond to `true?`
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top(required)>'
```

The test:

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe User do
  let(:valid_attributes) {
    {
      user_name: "username",
      email: "user@email.com",
      password: "password",
      password_confirmation: "password"
    }
  }
  describe "#downcase_email" do
    it "downcases an email before saving" do
      user = User.new(valid_attributes)
      user.email = "USER@EMAIL.COM"
      expect(user.save).to be_true
      expect(user.email).to eq("user@email.com")
    end
  end
end
```

My user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates :user_name, presence: true,
                        uniqueness: true

  validates :email, presence: true,
                    uniqueness: true,
                    format: {
                      with: /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\Z/
                    } 

  before_save :downcase_email                    

  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase
  end                    
end
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: If I eliminate the uniqueness validation on user_name my test passes. Maybe an issue with having two unique validations? Everything works correctly in development.

Comment: What happens when you check `user.errors.full_messages`?

Comment: If I create a new user, `user.errors.full_messages` produces an empty array. `=> []` .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that even though a unique email test was passing, requiring a unique user name was preventing a save. Using Factory Girl with `username#{n}` got my test to pass.

Comment: This is not the answer to what you originally asked. Graciela or Rob should be given credit for the answer.

Comment: I should give credit to people that gave me solutions I had already tried and didn't work? Since my question was how to get a test to pass in test mode that worked fine in development, this seems like a proper answer to my question.

Comment: The first error you were getting was because you had the wrong RSpec syntax. The second was because your test was failing to create the necessary data. Completely different, as Rob W says.

Comment: If you bothered to read my comments you would see that Rob's solution did not get my test to pass. I have another application with the same exact test with the same exact syntax that does pass. It doesn't require a unique username though. The syntax used here also works in a third application that was used in a course I took. I did up vote both Rob and Graciela's answers, but they did not get my test to pass.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `be true` or `eq true`. But this is only part of problems because seems like you have validation error. For investigate this check errors in `user.errors`.

Comment: If you mean user.errors in the rails console. I can create a user just fine. No errors, and email in downcased. I've tried all of `be_true`,     `be true`,    `eq true`,     `be_truthy`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `be_true` to `eq true`. The way you have it, it's calling the `#true` method on a `TrueObject`.

Comment: More or less.  `expected: true got: false`

Comment: That's a completely different error. Now it's saying the expected behavior isn't happening, as opposed to the previous error which was a simple syntax error.

For some reason, your model is not passing validations. The simplest way to determine what is going on is to start up a rails console in sandbox mode (`bundle exec rails console --sandbox`), create a user model just as you did in your test's `let` statement, then call `save` and see what happens (or, alternatively, call `valid?` and then afterwards call `errors`). This will tell you what is going on.

Comment: Without using sand box, I had created a user in the console. It created the user with no errors. User was valid. Email was set to lowercase. I added a comment above about taking the uniqueness validation off of user_name makes my test pass.

Comment: *Created* is a loaded term here, did you initialize a `user` with an uppercase email and then call `save`, or did you just `create` a user? Your tests are doing the former, not the latter. Make sure you are doing it *exactly* in the order your test is doing it in the console.

Comment: I only bring this up  because your problem may be due to the fact that you are using a `before_save` callback to call the `downcase_email` method instead of using a `before_validation` callback. This means it validates first, which will fail, then changes the email after it saves, which it will never do. See the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)